# CouchDB - How to create dynamic design docs based on end user input

Tags: python, drupal, couchdb

I have been reading up more on CouchDB and really like it (master:master replication is one of the primary reasons I want to use it).

However, I have a query to ask of you guys... I cam from php, and used the Drupal CMS fairly often. One of my favorite (probably of the drupal community as a whole) was the 'Views' plugin written by MerlinOfChaos. The idea is that an admin can use the views ui system, to create a dynamic stream of content from the database. This content could be from any content type (blog posts, articles, users, image, et. al.) and could be filtered, ordered, arranged in grids, and so on. One simple example is creating a source of content for a animating slider. Where the admin could go in at any time and change what is shown in there. Though typically I would set it up as the most 5 recent of content type X.

So with something like mongo, I could kinda see how to could do this. A fairly advanced parser that would then convert what the admin wants into a db query. Since mongo is all based on dynamic querying, it is very doable. However, I want to use couch.

I have seen that I can create a view that takes a parameter and will return results based on that (such as a parameter of the 5 article id's you want displayed). But what if I want to be able to build something more advanced from the UI? would I just add more parameters? For example, say the created view selects all documents with the value 'contentType' = 'post' and the argument is the id/page title. But what if I want the end user to also be able to choose the content type that the view queries against. Or the 5 most recent articles as long as the content type is one of 3 different values?

Another thing this makes me think of, is once a view like this is created and saved to the db, and called for the first time, it spends the time to build the results. Would you do this on a production/live system?

Part of the idea is that I want an end user to be able to create a custom feed of content on their profile page based on articles and posts on the site. and to be able to filter them and make their own categories, so to speak and label them. Such as their 'tech' feed, and their 'food' feed.

I am still new to couch and still have reading to do. But this is something that was buggins me and I am trying to wrap my head around it. Since the product I have in mind is going to be heavily dynamic based on the end users input.

The application itself will be written in python

Comment: I'd be very concerned about the performance of a system that could have hundreds or thousands of design docs/views, each of which would be eventually run for every update to your database.

Comment: yes that is the point, I dont want all of those. so I am trying to figure out how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you would need to emit something like this in the view:

```
emit([doc.contentType, doc.addDate], doc); // emit the entire doc, 
// add date is timestamp (assuming)
```

or

```
emit([doc.contentType, doc.addDate], null); // use with include_docs=true
```

Then, when you need to fetch the listing:

```
startkey=["post",0]&endkey=["post",999999999]&limit=5&descending=true
```

Explain:

```
startkey   = ["post",0] = contentType is post, and addDate >= 0
endkey     = ["post",9999999999] = contentType is post, and addDate <= 9999999999
limit      = 5, limit to five posts
descending = true = sort descending, which is sort by adddDate descending
```

To overcome the drawback of updating views on live db,
you can also create a new design(view) doc.
So, at least your existing code and view won't be affected.

Only after your new view is created,
you deploy the latest code to switch to this new view,
and you can retire the older view.

Comment: i think I see what you are doing. what if now the user decides they only want posts from certain users. or if rather than just posts, they want to see posts as well as new images? for adding the author, I am guessing I would just add that to the above and default it to None, and if is None then dont use it/show all. How would I make the doc.contentType query based on a variable number of content types?

Comment: you have to determine the business logic before making the view. If want posts from certain users -- there is no really quick and easy way. However, you can add one more key (user) into the emit. For multiple contentType ... you have to determine first. like what you said, `if (doc.ContentType == 'posts' || doc.contentType == 'images') { emit(doc.addDate, doc); }`

Comment: could I do something like this?
  
    `contentType = ['posts', 'image'] # build this based on the parameters given to the view`  
    `if (contentType in doc.ContentType) { emit(doc.addDate, doc); }`